# How to set variables for local/server side on Java maven project

Tags: java, continuous-deployment

Would you please help how to set the variable used in my java program, without much worry as current I have to run my code locally on the windows machine.

so the entire files which I am reading are at windows d:// directory, consider having more file to read and write from different locations from windows D drive.
according to my business logic.

same directory structure I am using on my CentOS server side. but the problem is in CentOS directory starts with /home/dir1/ and so one, so who to make this thing work.
As on each time I build my jar for deploy into server side. I have to change those variable names according to with Windows or CentOS.

Do you have any other easy ways, because of many time while testing I forget to make those directory change before testing on windows and deploying on the server side.

Really much appreciated in advance for any help or any link which can guide me to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the path in your class, externalize the configuration. There are many options for that.

1. Pass the path using System properties:

   `java -Dfile.location=/home/dir1/ -jar jarfile.jar`

   In the program then, you can use that property:
   `File directory = new File(System.getProperty("file.location");`
2. If you run a main method in a class in the jar, pass program arguments:

   `java -jar jarfile.jar "D:/directory"`

   This can then be read in your main program

   `public static void main(String[] args) {
       File directory = new File(System.getProperty(args[0]);
       //... rest of the program`

There are many other options, including property files, environment variables, JNDI, all depending on your runtime environment.